# How to parallelize a function call with return ndarrays in python?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am looking for a way to solve my problem with the multiprocessing module. To give you a better understanding what I do, see my following Explanation.

**Explanation:**

My `input_data` is an ndarray with 282240 elements of type uint32
   '
   In the `calculation_function()` I use a for loop to calculate from
   every 12 bit a result and put it into the `output_data`

Because this is very slow, 'I split my input_data into, e.g., 4 or 8
   parts and calculate each part in the `calculation_function()`.

Now I am looking for a way, how to parallize the 4 or 8 function
   calls

The order of the data is elementary, because the data is in image and
   each pixel have to be at the correct Position. So function call no. 1
   calculates the first and the last function call the last pixel of the
   image.

The calculations work fine and the image can be completly rebuilt
   from my algorithm but I need the parallelization to speed up for time
   critical aspects.

**Summary:**
One input ndarray is devided into 4 or 8 parts. In each part are 70560 or 35280 uint32 values. From each 12 bit I calculate one Pixel with 4 or 8 function calls. Each function returns one ndarray with 188160 or 94080 pixel. All return values will be put together in a row and reshaped into an image.

**What allready works:**
Calculations are allready working and I can reconstruct my image

**Problem:**
Function calls are done seriall and in a row but each image reconstruction is very slow

**Main Goal:**
Speed up the function calls by parallize the function calls.

**Code:**

```
def decompress(payload,WIDTH,HEIGHT):
    # INPUTS / OUTPUTS
    n_threads = 4                                                                           
    img_input = np.fromstring(payload, dtype='uint32')                                      
    img_output = np.zeros((WIDTH * HEIGHT), dtype=np.uint32)                            
    n_elements_part = np.int(len(img_input) / n_threads)                                    
    input_part=np.zeros((n_threads,n_elements_part)).astype(np.uint32)                      
    output_part =np.zeros((n_threads,np.int(n_elements_part/3*8))).astype(np.uint32)        

    # DEFINE PARTS (here 4 different ones)
    start = np.zeros(n_threads).astype(np.int)                          
    end = np.zeros(n_threads).astype(np.int)                            
    for i in range(0,n_threads):
        start[i] = i * n_elements_part
        end[i] = (i+1) * n_elements_part -1

    # COPY IMAGE DATA
    for idx in range(0,n_threads):
        input_part [idx,:] = img_input[start[idx]:end[idx]+1]


    for idx in range(0,n_threads):                          # following line is the function_call that should be parallized
        output_part[idx,:] = decompress_part2(input_part[idx],output_part[idx])



    # COPY PARTS INTO THE IMAGE
    img_output[0     : 188160] = output_part[0,:]
    img_output[188160: 376320] = output_part[1,:]
    img_output[376320: 564480] = output_part[2,:]
    img_output[564480: 752640] = output_part[3,:]

    # RESHAPE IMAGE
    img_output = np.reshape(img_output,(HEIGHT, WIDTH))

    return img_output
```

Please dont take care of my beginner programming style :)
Just looking for a solution how to parallize the function calls with the multiprocessing module and get back the return ndarrays.

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

I transfered my problem into a less complex example:
Is it possible to parallize each iteration of the for loop where the function is called?

```
import numpy as np

def split(data,parts,step, length):
    data_array=np.zeros((parts,step))

    for i in range(parts):  
        data_array[i,:] = data[i*step:(i+1)*step]

    return(data_array)

def mul(arr, scalar):
    result = np.multiply(arr,scalar)
    return(result)

data = np.linspace(1.0, 100.0, num=24).astype(int)
parts = 4
length=len(data)
step = np.int(length/parts)
scalar = 2
data_array = split(data,parts,step,length)                      
res_array = np.zeros((parts,step))
print(data_array)

for idx in range(parts):
    test = data_array[idx,:]
    res_array[idx,:] = mul(test,scalar) # Line to be parallized !

print('\n',res_array)
```

Comment: I don't see the mentioned `calculation_function()` in your code

Comment: The function itself ist not relevant (it just calculates and returns values). Calculations work allready fine, so I want to keep it simple as possible. Relevant for me is how to parallize the 4 times function call.

Comment: Your edit should have been your question from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah thats correct..... Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**multiprocessing**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

```
import multiprocessing

def calculation_function(some_array):
    # some logic
    # return result

chunksize = 4    # points to the number of processes and number of chunks to be processed
with multiprocessing.Pool(chunksize) as p:
    results = (p.map(calculation_function, entire_ndarray, chunksize))
```

---

Now, `results` contains an iterable of processing results.

> `multiprocessing.Pool.map(func, iterable[, chunksize])` 
> This method
>   chops the ***iterable*** into a number of chunks which it submits to the
>   process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks
>   can be specified by setting ***chunksize*** to a positive integer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. See my new example which I just added to the post. Can you easy add your multiprocessing example to my new example to parallize each iteration?

Comment: @Chris72H, as was mentioned in my answer: `multiprocessing.Pool.map` function can split the whole initial array into needed number of chunks without custom `split()` functions

Comment: So when I undestand u right, than I just have to variate the chunksize to get a different number of parallel processes? I tried that and the bigger the chunksize is the longer takes the algo. I thought that I can say: make 4 parallisations and this takes x seconds. When I take 8 parallizations this would take 0.5 *x seconds..... Hmmmm... I still dont get this

Comment: Well... I just have to make the Array big enough (120.000 elements), then it is getting faster with a bigger chunksize. Thank you very much